# How to autoscroll in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, autoscroll

I am trying to build a chat in Meteor. But I am struggling to make the messages part(which is a div that takes up 80% of the screen) scroll down to the newest message when a) the page is loaded or b) a new message is sent/received

I have found various ways to do this in html/js like e.g. this:

```
function scrollToBottom(){
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
scrollToBottom();
```

But I cannot figure out how to integrate this into the Meteor app. I have tried to put this into the 'click' event of sending a message and into the helper that loads the messages. It did not work though. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try to do it on the onRendered event from your chat blaze template?

Comment: Good idea, I tried this `Template.chat.onRendered(function() {
  this.autorun(() => {
    function scrollToBottom(){
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    }
    scrollToBottom();
  });
});` which did not work:(

Comment: I do not know your code and your UI, but are you sure you want to scroll the window and not a div containing the chat? Maybe your scroll is working, but you do not want to scroll on the body  but on a specific element... Just guessing. Plus you are doing an autorun with no reactive data in the context, I don't get the point...

Comment: @JulienLeray yes I want to just scroll the div with the messages :)

Answer (score 1):

For the infinite scrolling you can use [alethes:pages](https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages).
You just need to define:

```
this.Pages = new Meteor.Pagination(YourCollectionName, {
    debug: true,
    availableSettings: {
        limit: true,
        sort: true,
        filters: true,
        settings: true
    },
    templateName: "items",
    infinite: true,
    infiniteTrigger: .9,
    infiniteRateLimit: 1,
    infiniteStep: 1,
    itemTemplate: "item",
    pageSizeLimit: 1000,
    perPage: 5,
    maxSubscriptions: 500,
    dataMargin: 30,
    sort: {
        created_at: 1
    }
});
```

And on the template render just set:

```
Pages.set({
        filters: {
            //Custom filters
        }
    });
```

Inside template:

```
<template name="items">
    <div class="chat-discussion">
        {{> pagesNav}}
        {{> pages}}
   </div>
</template>
```

You also need to define your itm template like this:

```
<template name="item">
   //You can write you item (message body) here
</template>
```

Comment: I am rather new to Meteor, so could you tell me where the this.Pages needs to go? Also, can I scroll inside a div with this?

Comment: You can place it inside the Collections directory where you have defined your schemas/collections.